# A problem with nested Arrays and accessing them

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

So, i'm like really new to coding in general and i'm going to tryout a coding bootcamp.
So right now i'm trying to prepare myself to the "entry test" that will be focused on Javascript basics.
I have this problem:

```
const charactersArray = [
    ['☆', 'D', 'a', '☆', '☆', 'r'],
    ['t', '☆', 'h', '☆', 'H', 'a'],
    ['c', 'k', '☆', 'e', '☆', 'r'],
    ['L', '☆', 'o', 'o', '☆', 'p'],
    ['S', '☆', 'k', 'y', '☆', 'w'],
    ['a', 'l', '☆', 'k', '☆', '☆'],
    ['☆', 'e', '☆', '☆', 'r', '☆']
];
let newArr = [];
for (i = 0; i < charactersArray.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; i < charactersArray[i]; j++) {
        }
    }
```

so I've got this far but i get stuck after this. I need to take off that star special letter and return a new array with only the characters. Any helping hand?
I want the array to be multidimensional, yes.

Comment: Apparently there's confusion in the answers about whether you want the result to be a regular array or a two-dimensional array. Please clarify.

Comment: did you forget to add .length to the characgtersArray[i] in the inner loop? : for (j = 0; i < charactersArray[i]; j++) {

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
let resultAr = charactersArray.map(arr => arr.filter(item => item != "☆"));
```

Adding one more solution with RegEx for finer control on inclusion/exclusion

```
let resultAr = charactersArray.map(arr => arr.filter(item => /[^\W]/i.test(item)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the desired result:

If you need one dimensional array then you can just spread the filtered arrays into a new one:

```js
const arr = [ ['☆', 'D', 'a', '☆', '☆', 'r'], ['t', '☆', 'h', '☆', 'H', 'a'], ['c', 'k', '☆', 'e', '☆', 'r'], ['L', '☆', 'o', 'o', '☆', 'p'], ['S', '☆', 'k', 'y', '☆', 'w'], ['a', 'l', '☆', 'k', '☆', '☆'], ['☆', 'e', '☆', '☆', 'r', '☆'] ];

const result = arr.reduce((r,c) => (r.push(...c.filter(x => x !== '☆')), r), [])

console.log(result)
```

If you need the same dimensions but filtered is the same without the `spread`:

```js
const arr = [ ['☆', 'D', 'a', '☆', '☆', 'r'], ['t', '☆', 'h', '☆', 'H', 'a'], ['c', 'k', '☆', 'e', '☆', 'r'], ['L', '☆', 'o', 'o', '☆', 'p'], ['S', '☆', 'k', 'y', '☆', 'w'], ['a', 'l', '☆', 'k', '☆', '☆'], ['☆', 'e', '☆', '☆', 'r', '☆'] ];

const result = arr.reduce((r,c) => (r.push(c.filter(x => x !== '☆')), r), [])

console.log(result)
```

Same can be achieved in more concise manner via [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const arr = [ ['☆', 'D', 'a', '☆', '☆', 'r'], ['t', '☆', 'h', '☆', 'H', 'a'], ['c', 'k', '☆', 'e', '☆', 'r'], ['L', '☆', 'o', 'o', '☆', 'p'], ['S', '☆', 'k', 'y', '☆', 'w'], ['a', 'l', '☆', 'k', '☆', '☆'], ['☆', 'e', '☆', '☆', 'r', '☆'] ];

const result = Array.from(arr, x => x.filter(y => y != '☆'))

console.log(result)
```

If you need a string:

```js
const arr = [ ['☆', 'D', 'a', '☆', '☆', 'r'], ['t', '☆', 'h', '☆', 'H', 'a'], ['c', 'k', '☆', 'e', '☆', 'r'], ['L', '☆', 'o', 'o', '☆', 'p'], ['S', '☆', 'k', 'y', '☆', 'w'], ['a', 'l', '☆', 'k', '☆', '☆'], ['☆', 'e', '☆', '☆', 'r', '☆'] ];

const result = arr.reduce((a,c) => a.concat(c.filter(x => x !== '☆').join('')), "")

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given OP's purpose, I don't think he/she is interested in reduce/map/filter/...(at least right now). Just a simple for loop to manipulate two-dimension array.

```
for (i = 0; i < charactersArray.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < charactersArray[i].length; j++) {
        if(charactersArray[i][j] != "☆") {
            newArr.push(charactersArray[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to flatten the two-dimensional array, and then use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the stars:

```
const result = [].concat(...charactersArray).filter(c => c !== '☆');
```

---

Complete snippet:

```js
const charactersArray = [
    ['☆', 'D', 'a', '☆', '☆', 'r'],
    ['t', '☆', 'h', '☆', 'H', 'a'],
    ['c', 'k', '☆', 'e', '☆', 'r'],
    ['L', '☆', 'o', 'o', '☆', 'p'],
    ['S', '☆', 'k', 'y', '☆', 'w'],
    ['a', 'l', '☆', 'k', '☆', '☆'],
    ['☆', 'e', '☆', '☆', 'r', '☆']
];

const result = [].concat(...charactersArray).filter(c => c !== '☆');

console.log(result.join('')); // DarthHackerLoopSkywalker
```

Comment: That's it. I need it to take off all the special star and put in a new Array and then put in a string the "answer". Now i just need to try to understand what you did here a little more.

Answer (score -1):

```
charactersArray.map((a)=>{
    return a.filter((c)=>{
        return c != '☆'});
});
```

->

```
[ [ 'D', 'a', 'r' ],
  [ 't', 'h', 'H', 'a' ],
  [ 'c', 'k', 'e', 'r' ],
  [ 'L', 'o', 'o', 'p' ],
  [ 'S', 'k', 'y', 'w' ],
  [ 'a', 'l', 'k' ],
  [ 'e', 'r' ] ]
```

It is what you want?

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you might want from this requirement

> I need to take off that star special letter and return a new array with only the characters.

```js
const charactersArray = [
    ['☆', 'D', 'a', '☆', '☆', 'r'],
    ['t', '☆', 'h', '☆', 'H', 'a'],
    ['c', 'k', '☆', 'e', '☆', 'r'],
    ['L', '☆', 'o', 'o', '☆', 'p'],
    ['S', '☆', 'k', 'y', '☆', 'w'],
    ['a', 'l', '☆', 'k', '☆', '☆'],
    ['☆', 'e', '☆', '☆', 'r', '☆']
];
let newArr = [];
charactersArray.forEach(function(subArrays){
  let subArray = subArrays.filter(subArray => subArray !== '☆');
  subArray.forEach(function(character){
    newArr.push(character);
  });
});
console.log(newArr);
```